# How to define the line limits inside a List with stacks on SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to have custom cells in a list, but the text in the V stacks doesn't wrap and make a second line. It ends with ... and doesn't go for a second, third, as much is needed line.

I've tried .linelimit(nil) and .linelimit(random number) and .scaledToFill() to every stack and view as well as to the list itself, but it didn't help me. Ultimately, I did \n and it worked, but that's not what I want.

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {

    List {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "a.square").font(.largeTitle)
                Text("Title 1").font(.largeTitle)
            }
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. ").font(.subheadline)
            }

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "b.square").font(.largeTitle)
                Text("Title 2").font(.largeTitle)
            }
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. ").font(.subheadline)
        }
    }//.lineLimit(nil)
}
}
```

I want to have the text "Lorem ipsom dolor..." wrapped and for a second line. The first picture is the problem, the second is the placebo with the \n resolution.

Xcode 11 beta 4
Thanks in advance!

[image: Problem]

[image: Placebo]

Answer (score 1):

I am only able to get the intended layout by using a ZStack with padding to correct the layout of the Views. Alternatively there could be possibilities with custom Alignment.

**EDIT:** You can also use a .frame(idealHeight: .infinity) modifier with the text field. It will extend but there is always one line missing.

```
truct MultiT: View {
       var body: some View {

    List {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {

            Image(systemName: "a.square")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding(.top, 8)
            Text("Title 1")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding(.leading, 40)

            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. ")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .padding(.top, 40)
        }

        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {

            Image(systemName: "b.square")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding(.top, 8)
            Text("Title 2")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding(.leading, 40)

            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lalallaa. ")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .padding(.top, 40)
        }
    }.lineLimit(nil)
}
}
```